# Expo AV: 'if' video has finished, go back to start

Tags: javascript, reactjs, expo, jsx, expo-av

I am trying to create a function in Expo AV where 'if' the video has finished playing, it automatically returns to the start. The restart() function that I created does not allow this. Please excuse me as I am quite new to this! This is my code:

```
export default function App() {
  const video = React.useRef(null);
  const [status, setStatus] = React.useState({});

  const restart = () => {
    if (video.status.didJustFinish) {
      video.current.playFromPositionAsync(0);
    }
  };

  restart();

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Video
        ref={video}
        style={styles.video}
        source={require("./assets/big_buck_bunny.mp4")}
        useNativeControls={false}
        volume={1.0}
        resizeMode={ResizeMode.CONTAIN}
        isLooping={false}
        onPlaybackStatusUpdate={status => setStatus(() => status)}
      />
      <View style={styles.buttons}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => status.isPlaying ? video.current.pauseAsync() : video.current.playAsync()}>
          {status.isPlaying ? (
            <>
              <AntDesign style={styles.icons} name="pause" size={50} color="white" />
            </>
          ) : (
            <>
              <AntDesign style={styles.icons} name="play" size={50} color="white" />
            </>
          )}
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View >
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the logic of your `restart` function in a `useEffect` hook and add `status` as the dependency to observe. Whenever `status` changes, the effect will run and start the video from the start if `didJustFinish` is `true`.

```
export default function App() {
  const video = React.useRef(null);
  const [status, setStatus] = React.useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    if (status?.didJustFinish) {
      video.current.playFromPositionAsync(0);
    }
  }, [status]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Video
        ref={video}
        style={styles.video}
        source={require("./assets/big_buck_bunny.mp4")}
        useNativeControls={false}
        volume={1.0}
        resizeMode={ResizeMode.CONTAIN}
        isLooping={false}
        onPlaybackStatusUpdate={status => setStatus(status)}
      />
      <View style={styles.buttons}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => status.isPlaying ? video.current.pauseAsync() : video.current.playAsync()}>
          {status.isPlaying ? (
            <>
              <AntDesign style={styles.icons} name="pause" size={50} color="white" />
            </>
          ) : (
            <>
              <AntDesign style={styles.icons} name="play" size={50} color="white" />
            </>
          )}
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View >
  );
}
```